# CORS issue with Google App Engine and custom domain when uploading files to blob storage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, cors

I am using Google App Engine with Java. My URL is social-outreach.appspot.com
I added a new domain for my app engine (app.rippleonline.in).

When I try to generate upload URL with the blob storage using

```
UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName(GCS_BUCKET_NAME + "/" + folder);
```

I am getting a URL with my real AppEngine URL (social-outreach.appspot.com).
When I try to upload to that URL I am getting the CORS issue since the URL only accept connections from social-outreach.appspot.com. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem. The trick is that the when the blobstore calls the upload handler in your app, it will use your apps response as its own response to the user. So in your upload handler, use `resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` (or scope it narrower than `*` if you like).